# Using 'new' keyword with struct in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, new-operator, dynamic-allocation

```
#include "PQueue.h"

struct arcT;

struct coordT {
    double x, y;
};

struct nodeT {
    string name;
    coordT* coordinates;
    PQueue<arcT *> outgoing_arcs;
};

struct arcT {
    nodeT* start, end;
    int weight;
};

int main(){
    nodeT* node = new nodeT; //gives error, there is no constructor
}
```

My purpose is to create a new `nodeT` in heap. Error is:

> error C2512: 'nodeT' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code - `coordT` has an implicitly-generated constructor, which does nothing. Do you really get an error from that code? What exactly does it say?

Comment: error C2512: 'nodeT' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: You have a different problem. The code you are providing compiles fine (Have you declared any constructor?) You can try pasting it to ideone or any other similar page to verify this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't define a parameterized constructor in coordT?

Comment: @SegFault: there is no `nodeT` in the code you posted, so whatever you're really compiling, it has some error that this code doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that's your complete code? If you've given your class a constructor with arguments, then that will suppress the implicit default constructor; you will get that error then. And what's a `nodeT`?

Comment: @Mike Seymour, I though I could simplify the question, but now I guess problem is not what I though, because coordT* coord = new coordT works fine but nodeT does not if used in same way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PQueue<arcT *>` does not have an appropriate default constructor, so a default constructor for `nodeT` cannot be generated by the compiler. Either make an appropriate default constructor for `PQueue<arcT *>` or add a user-defined default constructor for `nodeT` which constructs `outgoing_arcs` appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

If the currently posted code in the question is an exact copy, then the only possible cause for this error is that `PQueue<…>` doesn’t define a default constructor, and defines another constructor instead.

Otherwise this code would compile.

More precisely, since you didn’t define a constructor for your structures, C++ tries to auto-generate them. It can only do this, though, as long as all its member variables are appropriately default constructible or initialisable. `std::string` has a default constructor, and `coordT*`, being a pointer, can be initialised. So only `PQueue<…>` remains as the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

THis may not be your problem but you've only declared one pointer on this line in arcT :-

```
nodeT* start, end;
```

You've declared start as a pointer and end as an actual nodeT object. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: No, this is not what I wanted to do, I wanted both of them to be pointer, you saved me a lot of time